# C# - Get data using EF code first - DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following 2 classes. I am using EF code first with existing database.

```html
 public class Asset
    {       
        [Key]        
        public decimal AssetId { get; set; }
        
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string AssetNumber { get; set; }
        
        public decimal? DistrictId { get; set; }   
       
        public virtual District District { get; set; }       

    }
```

```html
 public class District
    {        
        [Key]
        public decimal? DistrictId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string DistrictCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }       
    }
```

I need to get the list of assets where DistrictId is not null.

I am using following c# code:

```html
IQueryable<CustomClass> assets = dbContext.Assets 
             .Where(a => a.DistrictId != null)
            .Select(a => new CustomClass
            {
            });
```

I believe using navigation properties, you don't need to explicitly say- Where(a => a.DistrictId != null). I am unsure about it. So can you suggest what is the better way of getting list of assets where DIstrictId is not null.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried: 
IQueryable<CustomClass> assets = dbContext.Assets 
             .Where(a => a.District != null)
            .Select(a => new CustomClass
            {
            });

or even just: IQueryable<CustomClass> assets = dbContext.Assets 
             .Where(a => a.DistrictId.HasValue)
            .Select(a => new CustomClass
            {
            });

?

Comment: I have tried IQueryable<CustomClass> assets = dbContext.Assets .Where(a => a.District != null) .Select(a => new CustomClass { }); - It is working. But not sure it is the best way of achieving the result.

Comment: I don't think there's a better way.  It's right to the point.  How could it be done any simpler?  I don't think it can.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying directly against Assets, you're not actually using the Asset <-> District relationship.

If you were trying to get a list of Assets with Districts included, or a list of Districts and their Assets, you would be using the Navigation properties.

For the result you're trying to get, as HaukurHaf said in his comment what you're doing is the most straightforward method.

Answer (score 0):

That's as straight forward as can be, note that the `DistrictID` is only defining the relationship, it is not the navigation property, `District` is.

To verify you could do

```
// Eager loading all District properties and then filtering
List<CustomClass> assets = dbContext.Assets
    .Include(a => a.District)
    .ToList()
    .Where(a => a.District != null)
    .Select(a => new CustomClass {})
    .ToList();

// Your initial query.
List<CustomClass> assets2 = dbContext.Assets
    .Where(a => a.DistrictID != null)
    .Select(a => new CustomClass {})
    .ToList();
```

You will see they both eventually have the same list.